# jQuery Image Cropper with Uploader

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading, jcrop

I have been attempting to use a mashup of jquery plugins found on [this website](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/17/jquery-image-cropper-with-uploader/). as far as i can tell this is a pretty good peice of code, just have a couple of issues.

my main issue is that if i attempt to upload a file that is larger than the max file size in firefox it sends a javascript alert saying "error" which it is supposed to do but then crashes firefox and i have to physically end the process.

my next issue is that when you do upload an image and specify the crop target it doesnt actually seem to crop it rather just resize the the image to fit the samll region.

I would happily plough through the code myself but i know very little about javascript and next to nothing on jQuery, i do however know a fair bit about php so that side of things shouldnt be too bad.

hope someone can help,
Nate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize the image in Javascript - i imagine all it does is change the image tag. You need to send the resize coordinates/height/width to your backend and then resize it there.

Comment: i believe thats what jCrop does but like i said i cant follow the the js through because i dont understand half of it

Comment: Do you use Firebug or a similar tool? Check to see if it sends a XHR request to the server with resize coordinates. But usually (allways?) a jQuery plugin won't handle any of the backend business.

Comment: yes i use firebug i will run the script and check now, do you have any idea why the script would cause the other error

Comment: I'd guess a crash like that is because of a memory leak, maybe a endless loop?

Comment: where would i look to see if a xhr request is sent i went throught the upload process with the console open set to show everything but nothing came up

Comment: Uploads would be under the "net" tab, AJAX/XHR requests usually show up in both console and net

Comment: just ran through the process with only the xhr tab selected and no requests were sent

Comment: Well nothing is communicated via AJAX then - I suggest you look more closely at the documentation to get it to work :)
But i assume the file is actually uploaded since you can see it

Comment: yes whichever file i choose is put in the correct place just not as it should be. well looks like im just gunna have to crack out the books and learn js

Comment: @Nate My guess is you can't get any further without adding something to the plugin, you need to somehow send the coordinates of the resize to the backend and resize it there - You can probably find it in the documentation :)